# how to print the lines of a file that are multiples of 3 like 3rd, 6th, 9th line etc

Tags: unix

I have a file and I want only lines that are multiples of 3. Is there any UNIX command to perform this task?

Answer (score 7):

This makes it:

```
awk 'NR%3==0' file
```

`NR` stands for number of record, which in this case is number of line. So the condition is "(number of line / 3) having modulus 0" === "lines that are multiple of 3".

#### Test

```
$ cat file
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello4
hello5
hello6
hello7
hello8
hello9
hello10
$ awk 'NR%3==0' file
hello3
hello6
hello9
```

Answer (score 5):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n 0~3p filename
```

You can start at a different line by changing the number before the `~`, so to start with the first line instead, it'd be:

```
sed -n 1~3p filename
```

Example:

```
$ cat filename 
The first line
The second line
The third line
The fourth line
The fifth line
The sixth line
The seventh line
$ sed -n 0~3p filename 
The third line
The sixth line
$ sed -n 1~3p filename 
The first line
The fourth line
The seventh line
```

Alternatively, with a non-GNU sed like BSD sed:

```
$ sed -n '3,${p;n;n;}' filename 
The third line
The sixth line
```

Comment: @Kevin sorry, this requires GNU sed - presumably you have BSD sed instead (which would be the case if you were on a Mac).

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a way to do it with BSD sed?

Comment: +1, it is always good to also have the `sed` command for such purpose.